# How to check current branch head compare to default branch in GitLab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

GitHub web shows where is the selected branch compare to default branch. For example here `dev` is the default branch and I have selected `qa` branch. It shows that `qa` branch is 1 commit behind dev.
[image]

Does GitLab have the same kind functionality in UI.?

Answer (score 0):

Sure!
Navigate to `Repositories` > `Branches`, the list of branches has an indicator (before status icon and `Merge Request` button)
once you hover above, it explains "N commits behind ... M commits ahead"

[image: commits]

Clicking on `Compare` brings detailed diff in commits and files